# Access Object in Pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug

i wanna to access at my var tab in my console on front

this is my backend code

```
let tab= global.queue.GetListOfTraitement();
res.render('index', { title: 'Express', test: tab});
```

the result in backend console

```
[ status {
Type: 'File',
NomFichier: 'F1504365806Mcmhs784.avi',
Depart: 1504880910657 },


status {
Type: 'File',
NomFichier: 'F1504364893Euyza324.avi',
Depart: 1504881249064 } ]
```

my pug file

```
extends layout
block content
h1= title
p Welcome to #{test}
h2= title
script.
  console.log(test);

div
div
```

my result web page

```
Express

Welcome to [object Object]
Express
```

my result in console web

```
ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

my object is send has string [object Object] i can't acces of property  of my object.

Can you help me please?

Comment: have you tried `Welcome to #{test.anyPropertyHere}` ?

Comment: yes this is undedfined, this is the reason why i wan't to have console.log() on browser

Answer (score 0):

i have the solution, i can't show the index number with my console on backend, now i know i have index number

```
block content
h1= title
p Welcome to #{test[0].Type}
h2= title
table
```

But i always don't know how to pass object from backend to frontend.

Comment: in fact the you already know to pass an object from back to front, but i don't think you can display it raw like this and you have to display properties instead. If you want to use this object in your front javascript you'll have to play with interpolation (it's a bit tricky and i nver get the logic behind).

It seems that your tabs var is an array thought.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to a string, with JSON.Stringify() then you can display the content of the object.